# How to get words start with # in an string

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex, string

I am trying to read the hashtags in the browsers and check if two specific hashes exists.
Here is an example:

```
#world#player3#track1
```

So I want to check if the above string contains hashtags `player` or `track`, and if so, then it should return the those hashtags.

such as: `player3` and `track1`

I tried to achieve it with the following code but its not working:

```
var str = "#player1#track2"
if (str.length > 0 && str.indexOf("player") >= 0) {
  var player = str.substr(str.indexOf("player"), str.indexOf("#"));
  var track = str.substr(str.indexOf("track"), str.indexOf("#"));
  console.log(player + "" + track);
};
```

Any ideas how to achieve that?

Comment: Please read [ask]. Key phrases: "Search, and research" and "Explain ... any difficulties that have prevented you from solving it yourself".

Comment: Also, please clarify this part: "So I want to check if the above string contacts hashtags player or track, and if so, it should return the those strings so i can know their numbers."

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan, EDITED. The reason I didn't add my code in first place is that it does not close to what i want to achieve.

Comment: Why don't you just use `str.indexOf("#player")`?

Comment: @Barmar well it will only return the number that '#player' starts. In that case i need to know where this string finished. the value can be '#player1' or `#player3627`. I was looking for a method that once '#player' is found then it gives its string until the next '#'. So I can have the whole  string of '#player'. Hope it makes sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a regular expression to match the hashtag prefix followed by any digits.

```js
var str = "#player1#track2"
var player = str.match(/#player\d+/);
player = player ? player[0] : "";
var track = str.match(/#track\d+/);
track = track ? track[0] : "";
console.log(player + track);
```

Answer (score 1):

What if you have several "player" or "track" hashtags? In that case I guess that you may want something like this:

```
var strings = str.split('#');
for ( var i = 0; i < strings.length; i++ ) {
    if ( strings[i].indexOf("player") >= 0 || strings[i].indexOf("track") >= 0 )
        console.log(strings[i] + " ");
  }
```